# Why doesn't "cvs --help | less" work?

Tags: pipe, less, stderr

I don't know why, but piping `cvs --help` to `less` doesn't work. Probably it's because `cvs --help` outputs not to standard output(1) or error output(2), but somewhere else. Could you tell me where does it output?

Answer (score 9):

The reason is because there's two types of output.

- Normal output (`STDOUT`)
- Error output (`STDERR`)

`cvs --help` prints the help info to `STDERR`. The pipe (`|`) is expecting data that was written to `STDOUT` so that it can be read `STDIN`.

In order to get the help text from `STDERR` to `STDOUT` (so that it's readable by the pipe) you need to redirect it.

```
cvs --help 2>&1 | less
```

Further explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21).